Can't install cmake with MSYS2 MSYS as exit with no error
I'm trying to install cmake on my Windows 10 machine with MSYS2 using
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake

After conferming the installtion with Y it kind of start downloading but then it exits with no error (see screenshot)

If I try to re-run the command it says that the database is locekd
error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
error: could not lock database: File exists
  if you're sure a package manager is not already
  running, you can remove /var/lib/pacman/db.lck

So I need to remove the lock with rm -r /var/lib/pacman/db.lck manually.
For some reason it seems that I can't even download the package
I've tried to download another packge like
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc

And it correctly downloads and install it
I can't find what's the issue with the cmake
